# Designing Tables for Order System

Tags: database-design

This is a scenario which I often encounters:

Normalization often requires us to design tables in a way which data does not repeat itself.

Example of a typical Order entry which shows the following information:

1. Product Description.
2. Product Price.

Example of a normalized database, the order table would probably has the the PK of the Product Table (which contain the product description, pricing).

However, the product pricing might increase / decrease after the customer makes an order.

Should I store the pricing of the product at the time of transaction into the order table as well?

Is there any better solution to this type of issue?

Comment: One thing: **don't** call your table `Order` since that's a reserved SQL keyword (as in `ORDER BY`) - call it `Orders` or something else!

Comment: @marc_s Nooooo don't pluralize my table names!!

Comment: @Yuck: well, then call it `OrderHead` or something.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although normalization does reduce redundant information, "redundant" is a technical term with a narrow meaning. In this context, *redundant* means the same values with the same meaning.

It should be clear that "current price" and "price at the time the order was placed" (or "price the customer agreed to pay") don't have the same meaning, even if the values happen to be identical.

There are several ways to model that. But the critical insight is that you're talking about two completely different things when you talk about prices this way.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  I would use an OrderLine table to store each line on an order.  Store the price that the prodcut was sold for.  You could also store any discounts that were given.

Answer (score 2):

Catcall's answer is awesome. Should be given the correct answer. But to extend the point, the column names should also be different. If you have two columns in the two tables with the same name, I expect that the data in them to means the same thing. Having a column called "price" isn't helpful to anyone trying to understand your model. Extended_price, Price_at_sale, MSRP, etc. all help me understand the data at first glance.

Another way to look at this is how will you account for coupons/discounts/bogo offers/bundles? If I buy an item for $5 but have a $1-off coupon. Did I sell that product for $5 or $4? If you say $5 then you could have a separate line-item in the detail table for the -$1 but if you studied the profitability of that product you could miss those discounts.